# Context menu not appearing properly on listview item click

Tags: android, listview

So, with the below code i get the value of listview item i clicked and copy it to clipboard, so the user can paste it later.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {
                    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt);
                    registerForContextMenu(textView);

                }
            }
    );

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    //user has long pressed your TextView
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, Menu.NONE, "Copy");

    //cast the received View to TextView so that you can get its text
    TextView yourTextView = (TextView) v;
    copiedMSG = yourTextView.getText().toString();
    //System.out.println("Message Copied = : " + copiedMSG);
}

// This is executed when the user selects an option
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:
            ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            cm.setText(copiedMSG);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This works just fine but the problem is that the context menu appears only at the second time i click an item.The first time i click an item nothing at all happens.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the Context Menu is not registered for the `TextView` until the first click (this happens in your `OnItemClickListener`).

If you want the view to be registered for a Context Menu initially, you should do it in the `getView()` function of your list's adapter.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I actually tried that  in my custom adapter but i got "Cannot resolve method registerForContextMenu" error

Comment: You need to pass in a reference to you `Activity` and use that to register your views (`registerForContextMenu()` is a method on all `Activity` classes).